# Using Powershell Variables in a File-Stored Query with SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2012, powershell

I'm attempting to run some SQL through Powershell, using a wrapper function in PS to run the SQL command. As well, my SQL is in its own independent file and not hard-coded inline to the Powershell script, which would make what I'm trying to do trivial. What I need is to be able to have SQL Server do is to access the Powershell variable and use it in the query I'm sending. xp_cmdshell is coming up as a potential option to do this with, but I'd sooner not expose myself to the security vulnerabilities there if I don't have to.

Here's some pseudocode to get my idea across easier:

PSScript.ps1:

```
$var = 1
$query = query.sql
$con = connection(server_connection_params)
$command = New-Object System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand $sqlCommand,$connection
$command.ExecuteScalar()
```

Query.sql:

```
SELECT * FROM table WHERE field = $var;
```

Is there any way I could access `$var` in this fashion given how I'm calling the SQL in Powershell?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I expect the sample query you gave is basic, so my offer is basic but I think should work for you even with complex script files that require multiple variables to be passed/replaced.

The key here is you need to have a place holder in your script files that you can easily search for in PowerShell, then just `replace` it with that value.

An example query:

```
SELECT * FROM sys.databases WHERE name = 'var1'
```

In this example I am going to pull that query in from a file and then search for the `var1` value, replacing it with the database name I want to query for...

```
$var = 'MyDatabase'
$query = Get-Content .\Sample.sql | foreach {$_.replace("var1",$var)}
```

Example usage:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

This is easily solved using [sqlcmd.exe and scripting variables](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188714.aspx), if you can call an external utility instead of using `System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand`

You'd just have this in your Query.sql file:

`SELECT * FROM table WHERE field = '$(var)';`

And then you'd call `sqlcmd.exe` like this:

`sqlcmd -S <your server name> -b -i Query.sql -v var=$var`

- `-S` names the server to connect to.
- `-b` turns on "batch mode",
  where any error aborts the subsequent commands.
- `-i` runs the SQL from the named file
- `-v` names a variable to substitute

You can provide multiple `-v` flags if you need more than one variable to be substituted.